# (error)ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy intentando hacer una grafica parecida a los latidos de un corazon, pero no entiendo porque me sale el error

> `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

Mi código es:

```
def simul(pres, maxi,  ctrl):
    prueba = []
    print("Resultado:")
    while ctrl <= 1000:
        prueba.append(pres)
        if pres < maxi:
            pres += 4
        elif pres >= maxi:
            pres -= 15
        print(ctrl, "Segundos ")
        print("Presion:", prueba[ctrl], "mmHg.")
        print("\n")
        ctrl += 1
    pyplot.plot(ctrl, prueba)
    pyplot.show()
```

Y como es una función uso estos valores:

```
simul(10, 90, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot.plot` necesita dos **iterables** de la misma longitud que indican los valores en el eje `x` y en el eje `y` respectivamente para cada punto. El problema es que `ctrl` es un entero, no un iterable de la misma longitud que `prueba`.

Lo más simple es que uses [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-range) para esto:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot



def simul(pres, maxi,  ctrl):
    prueba = []
    segundos = range(ctrl, 1000+1)
    print("Resultado:")
    for s in segundos:
        print(f"{s} segundos")
        print(f"Presion: {pres} mmHg.\n")
        prueba.append(pres)
        if pres < maxi:
            pres += 4
        else:
            pres -= 15

        # print(f"{s} segundos")
        # print(f"Presion: {prueba[s]} mmHg.\n")

    pyplot.plot(segundos, prueba)
    pyplot.show()

simul(10, 90, 0)
```

Comment: El valor de pres se queda como 10, y no cambia, que se puede hacer? @FJSevilla

Comment: Erik, perdón es un typo, no es  `print(f"Presion: {prueba[ctrl]} mmHg.\n")` sino  `print(f"Presion: {prueba[s]} mmHg.\n")`, o mejor mueve los prints al inicio del `for` antes del condicional y evita el indizado haciendo simplemente `print(f"Presion: {pres} mmHg.\n")`. Voy a corregirlo.